# JSP Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, portlet

We are having a Portal Page where we have implemented pagination apart from that to tracking purpose we have kept two hidden variables named `"performaction"` and `"sortParameter"`.
initially the values of these hidden parameters will be `""`, but once the action like previous or next or some sort is performed on the page we are setting the hidden parameters and submitting the page in a javascript method, code for the same is

```
$("#my-data-table_next").on('click',function(){
$("#performaction").val("next");
$("#manageProductList").submit();

});

$("#my-data-table_previous").on('click',function(){
$("#performaction").val("prev");
$("#manageProductList").submit();

});

function submitForm(parameter){
$("#performaction").val("sort");    
$("#sortParameter").val(parameter);
$("#manageProductList").submit();
 }
```

now when we are pressing f5 on the page it is actually re-submitting the page 
with the values of parameters taking the previously assigned one i.e. if we click next,
value of performaction is next now we click f5 it is again resubmitting the page with the value of performaction coming out to be "next" again.

This is not we wanted, so is there's any way to avoid resubmitting of page when we press f5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: store value in session variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    e=e||window.event;
    if (e.keyCode === 116 ) {
      e.keyCode = 0;
      alert("This action is not allowed");
      if(e.preventDefault)e.preventDefault();
      else e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: And what if the user presses ctrl + r to refresh? Or indeed hits the browser's refresh button?